# start firewalld.service VIA ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, redhat, systemctl

we have very strange problem when we configure and start the firewall on remote machine

when we run VIA ssh the following command ( from bash script ) ,

- we have redhat 7 machine

  systemctl start firewalld.service

example from script:

```
ssh $USER@$IP systemctl enable firewalld.service
ssh $USER@$IP systemctl start firewalld.service
```

then we get message about timeout from command - systemctl start 
firewalld.service

but when we run the - systemctl start firewalld.service manual on machine

then we accessed  to run it

so why VIA SSH we cant run the command but local we can run it ?

what are the differences here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a Redhat 7 machine at hand, so I can't show exact values. But:

When you log in, you usually get a rich environment for your convenience during interactive sessions. Depends on your setup, of course, because you can set *any* environment you want adding statements to /etc/profile, $HOME/.bashrc and in many more ways.

In contrast, when just issuing a remote command, you get a more minimum environment; some directories may not in your PATH environment variable e.g.

An easy way to see the different environments will be the following thwo sessions:

```
ssh $USER@$IP env
```

versus

```
ssh $USER@$IP
env
exit
```

You may start by comparing the PATH values and try running your command `systemctl enable firewalld.service` on the interactive shell, but after changing the PATH variable to the non-interactive variant of it.

If that doesn't give you a bingo yet, set the entire environment of your interactive session exactly as in the non-interactive version.

There's another difference for the `ssh host command` way: you don't get a tty; you see this issuing the command `tty`. Your interactive sessiong will answer something like `/dev/pts/3`, while `ssh host tty` will answer `not a tty`. I'm note aware of systemctl being dependent on a tty or even behave the slightes bit differently, but other commands it envokes may do so. You may require ssh to allocate a tty adding the -t switch like `ssh -t $USER@$IP systemctl enable firewalld.service` to see wether it makes a difference.